# Servicestack with Monotouch throwing compile errors with DTOs after referencing DLL

Tags: compiler-errors, servicestack, xamarin, dto

I've created my DTOs in a separate project whilst developing the server side servicestack code in VS Express 2012 on a windows 8 machine (and tested with both .Net 4 profile and with .Net 4.5 profile).

The compiled DTO library is then copied over to and referenced in my Xamarin studio project so that I can create the IOS app and make use of the DTOs there.  Unfortunately, this throws an error:

```
Error CS0246: The type or namespace name `User' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? (CS0246) (App1.Logic)
```

(Doesn't necessarily have to be 'User' it happens for all my DTOs).

If I create the DTOs from a class file within Xamarin it works but when importing a compiled library of DTOs it fails although I can browse through the DLL and view it in Xamarin studio and create/reference the DTOs and their parameters in the code.

The monotouch IOS app has namespace 'App1.Logic' and my DTOs have namespace 'Contracts.DTO.'  I've referenced them correctly.

I've tinkered with .Net profiles too but no luck.

Any ideas?